# HOW TO REMOVE DUPLICATES IN A ROW IN PYTHON

Tags: python, string, list, duplicates

Hi I need to remove the duplicates in python but only when they are in a row. For example:

Input: AAABBCCDDAA
Output:ABCDA

Could you please help me? thnks.

Comment: Have a look at [sets](https://realpython.com/python-sets/)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn more about text processing in Python3 I recommend training on [codingame.com](https://codingame.com).

```
def removeDuplicates(inp):
output =""
lastCharacter=""
for character in inp:
    output+=character*(character!=lastCharacter)
    lastCharacter=character
return output

inpTest ="AAABBCCDDAA"
print(removeDuplicates(inpTest))
```

> ABCDA